# ESP8266 MQTT periodically disconnecting

Tags: esp8266, mqtt

I use an MQTT to communicate with an ESP8266. I'm using cloudmqtt.com and PubSubClient. Sometimes the ESP disconnects from the MQTT and reconnects.
I checked the log from cloud and I got this data

```
2019-02-18 20:11:18: New connection from 89.64.15.184 on port 18127.

2019-02-18 20:11:22: New connection from 89.64.15.184 on port 18127.

2019-02-18 20:11:35: New connection from 89.64.15.184 on port 18127.

2019-02-18 20:11:35: New client connected from 89.64.15.184 as ESP8266Client-80:7D:3A:69:6C:2E (c1, k15, u'userName').

2019-02-18 20:11:53: Client <unknown> has exceeded timeout, disconnecting.

2019-02-18 20:11:53: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.

2019-02-18 20:11:56: Saving in-memory database to /var/lib/mosquitto/18127/db.

2019-02-18 20:11:58: Client ESP8266Client-80:7D:3A:69:6C:2E has exceeded timeout, disconnecting.
```

in setup I have this method:

```
void setupMQTT() {

  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println("Connecting to MQTT...");
    String clientId = "ESP8266Client-";
    clientId += WiFi.macAddress();
    if (client.connect(clientId.c_str(), mqttUser, mqttPassword )) {

      Serial.println("connected");

    } else {

      Serial.print("failed with state ");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      delay(2000);

    }
  }
  client.publish("esp/blind/out", "hello world");
  client.subscribe("esp/blind/in");
}
```

and in loop I have

```
client.loop();
```

without any delay.

I think that the ESP id in MQTT cloud is unique, because I use the MAC address.

Comment: which version of arduino/esp8266 are you using - I ask, because I had to put in a `delay(10)` or so in `loop` for some ESP chips when using the latest (2.5.0dev) branch

Comment: I use wemos D1 mini with ESP-12F and about month ago I update firmware because I wanted to try micropython

Comment: but your code isn't written in micropython .... it looks like typical arduino (i.e. C/C++) ... which version of the esp8266 arduino core are you using? Actually, nevermind, try adding a `delay(10)` in your main loop or even a `yield()`

Comment: no it isn't written in micropython it's written in c++, adding delay(10) do nothing. How can I check a esp8266 arduino core version ?

Comment: you downloaded it and installed it ... what did you download and install ... another possibility is the router you connect to- which make model? (e.g I have a linksys wrt32x - and ESP's have lots of issues staying connected to it)\

Comment: I have version 2.5 updated from 2.5 beta 2. I connect esp to airport from apple

Comment: try setting a lower "keep alive" ... e.g. `#define MQTT_KEEPALIVE 10` before `#iclude <pubSubClient.h>`

Comment: It works, thank you very much for helping

Comment: I have the same problem again, I added #define MQTT_KEEPALIVE 10 and delay(50)